# displaying different output

Tags: php, html

I am creating a game but I have a problem on what syntax I need to use. What I want to do see if I type any letter in text box the displaying letter will be different like I type letter a or any letter the text box will display the letter H then another letter like B the text box will display E until the text box will display hello world. (but what i type is not hello world)

This is just for fun. where I ask a question but I'm already typing the answer. So the people see it in different views.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please rephrase in short sentence. Good punctuation would help.

Comment: Include your code

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```js
var gameSentence = "Hello World!";
var gameInput = document.querySelector("#gameInput");

gameInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  gameInput.value = gameSentence.substring(0, gameInput.value.length); 
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="gameInput" />
```